# How to prevent Messages interpreting the @ symbol as a contact's name (inside an email address)

Tags: ios, messages, big-sur

With Messages in macOS Big Sur (and iOS 14), you can now 'mention' a person's name using the @ sign. This feature is described in [Messages User Guide > Send messages > Use mentions in conversations](https://support.apple.com/en-au/guide/messages/icht35827/14.0/mac/11.1#aria-icht1f451683), and on the [Big Sur features](https://www.apple.com/macos/big-sur/features/#messages) page.

That's all fine and dandy when you're trying to mention someone's name. When you're just trying to enter an email address, it can be a downright nuisance. For example, if you're trying to enter bill@bobs-car-wash.com, and Bob happens to be the name of someone in the chat group, it'll automatically convert @bob into a shimmery blue capitalised 'Bob', and the comment will be directed to Bob.

I cannot find any other mention of this annoying behaviour anywhere. I guess it's reasonably unlikely for most people to stumble across (where the name of a contact is at the beginning of the domain name) and perhaps Apple didn't even consider this possibility.

Does anyone know of a way to work around this issue? (If not, I'll send feedback to Apple.)